# Opening a pop up window for multiple choices?

Tags: batch, popups

I am working on a `batch` script that runs a playlist of videos, opening them one by one, and asking for an action in between videos. Is there a way to open a pop up window for multiple choices? This pop up window should close in a matter of seconds if no action is taken, so that the playlist can continue. No native Microsoft command line tool does this, looking for a workaround.

Comment: What workaround do you think of? I think your only option is to abandon batch script and use another programming language.

Comment: @MátéJuhász You're right, this is where I must admit defeat and learn an actual language, thanks.

Comment: there are several options to achieve that, I wrote one example as an answer, it would be too much for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```bath
<# :^ Starting bat script and PowerShell comment 

@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0" & color 0a 
echo & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title Batch files and Powershell hybrids
%__AppDir__%mode.com con:cols=080lines=009

echo. & echo. hybrid .cmd/.bat ^& ps1  
echo\=====================================

for /f usebackq^tokens^=*delims^= %%i in (`
set "_=0" ^& type "%~f0"^|powershell.exe -nOp -c -
   `)do 2>&1 (if "%%~i" == "[ Error 1 ]" (goto %:^| 
        )else if "%%~i" == "[ Error 2 ]" (goto %:^O 
        )else if "%%~i" == "[ Error 3 ]" (goto %:^V
        )else if "%%~i" == "[ Error 4 ]" (goto %:^?
        )else set/a "_+=1" && call %:^) !_! "%%~i")

if !_! equ 0 goto %:^?
endlocal & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe 01 | (
     echo/- The job is done!) & goto :eof 

%:^|
endlocal & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe 01 | (
     echo/- Canceled by user!) & goto :eof 
     
%:^?
endlocal & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe 01 | (
     echo/- Timeout reached!) & goto :eof 

%:^)
rem. ::  & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe 01 | (
echo\Clicked Itens #%~1: "%~2") & exit /b

%:^O
endlocal & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe 01 | (
     echo\Nothing selected by user) & goto :eof

%:^V
endlocal & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe 01 | (
    echo\#Error: no \subfolders) & goto :eof
    
:: End Bat Session and Starting PowerShell Script >" ::
#>

function SourceDirectory ([string]$Message,
    [string]$work_dir, [switch]$NoNewFolderButton )
{
    $browseForFolderOptions = 0
    $browseForFolderOptions += 512
 
    $app = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $folder = $app.BrowseForFolder(0, $Message, $browseForFolderOptions, $work_dir)
    if ($folder) { $selectedDirectory = $folder.Self.Path } else { $selectedDirectory = '' }
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($app) > $null
    return $selectedDirectory
}  

$work_dir = Push-Location $PSScriptRoot

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Select Folders use Control'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(330,200)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(560,20)
$label.Text = 'Please make a selection from the list below:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)
               
$Global:timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$Global:EndDate = ((Get-Date).AddSeconds(+10)).ToString("mmss")
$Global:timer.Add_Tick({ if ($EndDate -lt (Get-Date).ToString("mmss")) { 
              $timer.Stop(); $form.Close(); Write-Host '[ Error 4 ]'}})

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$listBox.SelectionMode = 'MultiExtended'

[void] $listBox.Items.Remove('Item *')

 if ((ls -ad $work_dir).count -eq 0){'[ Error 3 ]'; break
    } else { ls -ad $work_dir | ? {[void] $listBox.Items.Add($_) } }

$listBox.Height = 70
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Topmost   = $true; 

$timer.Start(); $result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel) {'[ Error 1 ]' ; break}
if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
     if ($listBox.SelectedItems.Count -gt 0) { (resolve-path($listBox.SelectedItems) | 
         select -ExpandProperty Path )| % { $_ } } else {'[ Error 2 ]'; break} }

Pop-Location ; exit
```

---

[image]

---

You can use hybrid bat with **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**, and with some searching on the examples available on the internet.

You can quickly adapt it so that it best suits your goal, a lot and take advantage of the resulting learning and consider migrating to **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**.

Below is an example using a script I made a few months ago to get a folder listing by multiple selection/click and which I adapted by adding output to following actions by the user:

- Selected items
- Unselected item
- Cancel click/close
- Timeout 10 seconds // if no actions

---

[image]

---

- [Start-CountDownTimer.ps1](https://github.com/proxb/PowerShell_Scripts/blob/master/Start-CountDownTimer.ps1)
- [Multiple selection list boxes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/multiple-selection-list-boxes?view=powershell-7.1)
- [Cancel button in a powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56527647/cancel-button-in-a-powershell-script)
- [An A-Z Index of Windows PowerShell commands](https://ss64.com/ps/)
- [How to add a timer in ps1 to quit the form after certain amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683471/how-to-add-a-timer-in-powershell-to-quit-the-form-after-certain-amount-of-time)

Answer (score 1):

Although there might be no "direct way", there are several work arounds e.g. doing a `time out` of the main script while a second script is doing the user query. The second script can for example write it's result into a file (or not, if it is ignored). After the time out the first script continues with evaluating the result (or cancelling the second script if it was ignored).

That all depends on the type of command terminal you want to use for the batch file e.g. powershell, cmd, or some other. Here are a few examples:

- [Here is](https://www.howtogeek.com/196873/how-to-add-a-timeout-or-pause-in-a-batch-file/) how to add a time out in cmd
- [Here is](https://blog.ipswitch.com/creating-a-timeout-feature-in-your-powershell-scripts) how to add a time out in a powershell